# How to change the colour of <lightning:input type="toggle" >?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, css, checkbox

I would like to change the standard color of the toggle in lightning input when it is checked or not. How can I perform it?

```css
.THIS .slds-checkbox_faux
{
    background-color: #ec54d4 !important;
}
```

In this way, it will be changed every checkbox.
Additionally, how can I distinguish the color when it is checked or not? I tried `.slds-checkbox_off` but it seems doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
.slds-checkbox_toggle [type=checkbox]:checked+.slds-checkbox_faux_container .slds-checkbox_faux{
    border-color: red!important;
    background-color: red!important;
}
```

Should work!
You can distinguish it with the checked property of the `slds-checkbox_toggle`. Following properties will be added only if the checkbox was also checked.